# JavaScript | Imported module breaking inside for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, module

I am writing a program which performs Eratosthenes' Sieve up to a given limit. This is the current code:

```
const { isPrime } = require(`./numPropFuncs.js`);

const limit = 30;
const primes = [];

const eratosthenesSieve = num => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            primes.push(i);
        };
    };
};

eratosthenesSieve(limit);

console.log(primes.join(`, `);
```

It imports the following module to test whether a number is prime:

```
const resources = require(`./factorList.js`);

const isPrime = num => {
    resources.factorList(num);
    if (resources.factors.length === 2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
};
```

Which in turn imports the following module which provides an array of all factors of a given number:

```
const factors = [];

const factorList = (num) => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      factors.push(i);
    };
  };
};
```

**Both modules have been tested to ensure they work and have been imported properly.** The issue is that when `isPrime()` is called inside the for loop of `eratosthenesSieve()` it returns `false` for every iteration, including when prime numbers are passed as the argument.

I am testing `eratosthenesSieve()` using 30 as the limit as it's easy to verify the result. The logged output should be the string: `2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29`. Instead it either logs nothing, or in the case of logging `primes` without `.join()`, []. After having the loop log `${i}: ${isPrime(i)}` on each iteration I realized `isPrime()` was returning `false` for every number (i.e logging "0: false" ... "30: false"). I tested `isPrime()` outside of `eratosthenesSieve()` and inside `eratosthenesSieve()` but outside the for loop and both times it worked properly.

I thought maybe it was a scope issue, and so I tried using a seperate variable, declared inside `eratosthenesSieve()` but outside the loop, as the test number instead of i:

```
const eratosthenesSieve = num => {
    let testNumber = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        if (isPrime(testNumber)) {
            primes.push(testNumber);
        };
        testNumber++;
    };
};
```

This had solved a different problem I was having with another program's loop, though that program didn't use `isPrime()`, (I don't remember what that program's issue was). However this solution did not work for the Eratosthenes' Sieve program.

I tried simply logging `${7}: ${isPrime(7)}` on every iteration while commenting out the rest of the code inside `eratosthenesSive()` just to see what would happen. Oddly enough, it logged `7: true` on the first iteration (the correct output, obviously), but logged `7: false` on every one of the 29 successive iterations.

Finally, I tried refactoring to have the loop start at 1 in case starting at 0 was causing problems. This also did not help.

I am at a loss as to what is going on here and how to fix it. Thank you so much in advance for your help. (My runtime environment is Node.js in VS code on MacOS Sonoma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're modifying the `factors` array for each call of your `isPrime()` function without ever resetting it. Because `factors` is global, the values you push into it persist even after the `isPrime()`/`factorsList()` function has finished executing. For example, if you call `isPrime(1)`, then `resources.factors` updates to be:

```js
[1]
```

Then on the next iteration, you call `isPrime(2)`, which results in pushing `1` and `2` onto the previous result, now `resources.factors` will be:

```
[1, 1, 2]
```

from here, `resources.factors` keeps growing, meaning your `resources.factors.length === 2` check in `isPrime()` will never be `true`.

Instead, make `factors` local to the `factorsList` function so that each call to `factorsList` is independent and returns the `factors` just for that call:

```js
const factorList = (num) => {
  const factors = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      factors.push(i);
    }
  }
  return factors;
};

module.exports.factorList = factorList;
```

Then you can use the returned array in your `isPrime` function:

```js
const isPrime = (num) => {
  const factors = resources.factorList(num);
  return factors.length === 2;
};
```